# The output repeats itself as many times as the letters inserted while trying to count the charts

Tags: java

```
private static void CountLetters(Scanner sc) {

    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    String s = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter a letter");
    char c = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);

    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == c) 
            res++;

        System.out.println(res + " " + c + " i " + s);
        }
```

The output repeats itself as many times as the letters. Any idea why and how to fix it?
Exemple of the current output:

Enter a string

Hello world
Enter a letter

l

0 l in Hello world

0 l in Hello world

1 l in Hello world

2 l in Hello world

2 l in Hello world

2 l in Hello world

2 l in Hello world

2 l in Hello world

2 l in Hello world

3 l in Hello world

3 l in Hello world

Comment: What are you expecting the code to output? Based on what I can see, the code is doing exactly what it is supposed to as it's written. Do you want it to just print 1 line that says the total count? If you do, move the print statement outside of the loop.

Comment: The “print” statement is inside the loop. To execute exactly once it should be after the loop’s closing brace.

Comment: omg how did I miss it. Thank you very much people! You are awesom :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your print statement exists within the loop, it's going to print the current count every time the loop is executed, which gives you the multiple lines/counts. Moving the print outside of the loop will ensure that it only executes once after the entire string has been parsed:

```
private static void CountLetters(Scanner sc) {
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        String s = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter a letter");
        char c = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);

        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == c)
                res++;
        }
        // Moved print statement outside of the loop; changed "i" to "in".
        System.out.println(res + " " + c + " in" + s);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put the output statement in your loop if you aren't tracking the code:

```
int res = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    if (s.charAt(i) == c)
        res++;
}
System.out.print(res + " " + c + " in" + s);
```